# what is the possible solution to start the workflow with user having Read, add and view permission?

Tags: workflow

i have created a custom list in share point with workflow enabled but when user add item in the list workflow is not enabled? what is the possible solution to start the workflow? Appreciate your response?

Answer (score 0):

To Start SPD workflow minimum Contribute Permission is require at List Level.